# Scrollbar without border

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have question about scrollbar. I've searched on google but I didn't find what I want. I want scrollbar like on YouTube. Without scaling web and have that big one border in black color.

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0h0w.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9pts.png
```

On the 1st link is that how I want. Transparent border on content of the website.
On the 2nd is what I have. The big border.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please add a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question, at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the width of the scrollbar as well as the border color using thsers selector ,

this is very close to what you mention in the first image but tweak it as you want

[Live example](https://codepen.io/HijenHEK/pen/eYvJMVd)
[Source W3S](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp)

```css
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  background : transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
 
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #818181;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width : 8px;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #8F8F8F; 
}
```

[image]

**this code will guarantee a transparent scrollbar background , but since it does not cover inner divs it will take the body bg-color and it will display next to your divs , if there are divs siding the scrollbar and have different color than the body it will give the illusion of having a bg-color even tho its not . Youtube dosnt let different color div ssides the bar thus nothing affects the looks of the scrollbar**

Comment: No, its same as mine, but only different color.  https://ctrlv.cz/i0KX 
This is Twitch scrollbar. I want this. No border around, only on content of web

Comment: just updated the post and the link no background no border similar to twitch

Comment: That picture you've sent is exactly what I want. But when I add the code you've sent to me I have still border there

Comment: what browser you have ?

Comment: https://en.designbydaniel.eu/

I'm sorry that I didn't write that web previously

Comment: @D4N13L. i have checked the style file ad you didn't apply it correctly you are missing the first two selector which contains the transparent background .

i have just fixed it , https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kZrSDggGSV3FkdOSSSfxJd-9jJoxCUgM

Comment: Oh, Thank you very much! Can you send me the code you repaired, please?

Comment: i just added that code in your stylesheet , i didnt find i all there and bare in mind it may act differently on different browser since its not 100% supported , consider verifying the answer and thumbs it up if it solves your issue .

Comment: i just said to you the same code in my answer . the first two selectors are missing from your site

Comment: Can I send you the CSS file and could you repair it, please? I am so dumb at this :/

Comment: What am I supposed to see on your profile?

Comment: my info ? and share with me your output

Comment: I don't see there any info

Comment: I only see your acc but I dont see any info

Comment: I've used your edited code and it's same still